# Embedded applications, similar to iAd, on Iphone OS

Tags: iphone

Apple [just announced the iAd platform as part of iPhone OS 4](http://www.engadget.com/2010/04/08/live-from-apples-iphone-os-4-event/).  It essentially is an embedded application with a unified interface where you close the embedded application using a small x in the corner.  This is obviously a nice experience for users, that could be used by other advertising platforms or to provide an embedded application such as dictionary service.

While details remains sketchy on the iPhone OS 4 public APIs, I am wondering if expert iPhone developers know whether this functionality can be replicated by third-party ad providers, or others interested in something like an embedded dictionary service.  Is this possible?

Comment: You mean that thing that was just announced 10 minutes ago?

Comment: Yes.  Is there a problem with not being months behind the curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like an embedded app already exists today. If a developer has integrated with the address book you can get full address book functionality including creating new address book entries as well as editing existing entries.

What's required to start the process is a view controller that's presented modally. The user interaction is limited to this new view controller and any other view controllers associated with it. When the user is done (or clicks on the small x in the corner in this case) the modal view controller is dismissed.

The interesting thing here is that the iAd platform presents a very flexible workflow, for lack of a better term, for different types of ads whereas the existing workflow in address book integration, for example, is less flexible and static. This may have to do with internals of the new OS entirely.

Back to your question, an embedded dictionary service would be fairly simple, relatively speaking, to build and is possible with the OS versions shipping today for the iPhone, iPod Touch, and iPad devices.

Comment: Can you call up an arbitrary view?  Like, say, Yelp reviews?  Do you have any sense for how dynamically serving the embedded apps, like iAd, might work?  Does this require new functionality?

Comment: Yelp reviews are totally possible. Create a view controller that pulls up a Yelp browser filling a table view with content. User selects an entry and a new view controller with Yelp reviews for that entry is pushed on to the navigation view controller.

Serving completely arbitrary embedded apps unknown at run time will definitely require new functionality. I'm not certain that functionality will be available to developers outside of Apple, however. It sounds like the ads are HTML5 based which means the embedded apps may be web apps with rich interaction.

Comment: Yes, it looks like they are really impressive HTML5 apps with lots of webkit specific css.

http://techcrunch.com/2010/04/08/apple-announces-iad-mobile-advertising-platform/

Comment: Can WebKit HTML5 apps access native SDKs, like maps?

Comment: Unlikely that HTML5 can access native maps. But they may have access to web maps.

Comment: SDK suggests it's a mix of stuff, with modal view being a big part.  Not clear whether the AdManager, which downloads content, is doable by third-parties.